# How can I determine Quality of a vowel/consonant without things like praat?

Tags: phonetics

Really is there any way I can determine quality of a vowel/consonant without praat?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, people used to do it in the olden days all the time. What's required is a course of training in auditory phonetics, where you are given examples of particular sounds like [ɑ] versus [a], performed by an expert, and you learn to distinguish between different sound types. The IPA (the organization) has a page with recorded [expert performances](https://www.internationalphoneticassociation.org/IPAcharts/inter_chart_2018/IPA_2018.html). In case you mean "phonation type", they do also include examples of breathy and creaky voice. However, you can only get a very rough categorization ("is breathy" vs "is modal"), and you can't get an acoustic measurement without a Praat-like program or similar specialized hardware such as a spectrograph that detects waveform properties.